# Update data linq in table jquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to create an update linq query & I generate table using jQuery so after update how do I save changes to data in the table?

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string updateselect_data(int ServiceID, string frequency, string Freq_Du, string Freq_Mil)
    {
        string query_update = "";
        try
        {
            Track_Data track = new Track_Data();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var update =
                from p in track.Serv
                where p.ServiceID == ServiceID
                select p;

            foreach (var q_update in update)
            {
                q_update.frequency= frequency;
                q_update.Freq_Du= Freq_Du;
                q_update.Freq_Mil= Freq_Mil;
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"] = ServiceID;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["frequency"] = frequency;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Freq_Du"] = Freq_Du;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Freq_Mil"] = Freq_Mil;

            try
            {
                track.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception();

            }
            update.ToList().ForEach(row => dt.LoadDataRow(new object[] {  
           row.ServiceID, row.Frequency, row.Freq_Du, row.Freq_Mil }, false));

            query_update = DataSetToJSON(dt);
             return query_update;

        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

JQUERY CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    $(function () {
            $('[ID*=btn_update]').on('click', function () {
            var ServiceID = '<%=Session["SID"]%>';
            var frequency='<%=Session["frequency"]%>';
                var Freq_Du = '<%=Session["Freq_Dur"]%>';
                var Freq_Mil = '<%=Session["Freq_Mil"]%>';
            debugger;
            var obj = {};
            obj.ServiceID = ServiceID;
            obj.frequency = frequency;
            obj.Freq_Dur= Freq_Du;
            obj.Freq_Mil = Freq_Mil;

            updatedata(obj);

        });
    });
    function updatedata(obj){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Maintenance.aspx/updateselect_data",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data:"{'SID:'"+ obj.ServiceID+"','frequency:'"+obj.frequency+"','Freq_Du:'"+obj.Freq_Du+"','Freq_Mil:'"+obj.Freq_Mil+"'}",
           dataType: "json",
        success:function(result)
        {
            debugger;
            var up = JSON.parse(result.d).response;

        }
    });
    }

</script>
```

i create table throgh jquery now first i want to update and want to check in console now when i do above code this show error s

Invalid object passed in JSON

Comment: Error message is loud and clear, You need to initialize these variables `ServiceID, Service_frequency, Next_Service`

Comment: Try something like this : update.ToList().ForEach(row => dt.LoadDataRow(new object[] { row.ServiceID, row.frequency, row.Freq_Du, row.Freq_mil}, false));

Comment: this show error Invalid object passed in JSON @jdweng

Comment: I don't think the column names from p in track.Serv are matching the column names in the c# code posted.   Try this instead : update.ToList().ForEach(row => dt.LoadDataRow(new { SID = row.ServiceID, frequency = row.frequency, Freq_Dur = row.Freq_Du, Freq_Mil = row.Freq_mil}, false));

Comment: this show error s.. Error 11 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataTable.LoadDataRow(object[], bool)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 12 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'object[]'

Comment: Please close this thread "Update data linq in table jquery"  because this is the duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129089/store-update-linq-query-and-pass-to-json   ...

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the following, but have not assigned any value.

```
int ServiceID ;
string Service_frequency;
string Next_Service;
```

For example;

```
int ServiceID = 1 ;
string Service_frequency = "Weekly";
string Next_Service = "Tomorrow";
```

Comment: You also completely changed the code, question, error and answer. If your previouis question was answered, and now you have another issue (which you did and do) you should ask another question and not completely refactor yours to suit the current position.