# Store update LINQ query and pass to json

Tags: c#, jquery, linq

I am trying to create an update linq query & I generate table using jQuery so after update how do I save changes to data in the table?

JQUERY

now i get ServiceID from table and i try to update record on the bases of ServiceID

i try this

```
                $(function () {
                    $('#services_schdulue').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                        debugger;
                        var row = $(this);
                        var ServiceID = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
                        var s = {};
                        s.ServiceID = ServiceID;


                    $('[ID*=btn_update]').on('click', function () {
                        debugger;
                        var ServiceID = s.ServiceID;
                         var frequency = $('#txt_repeat').val();
                        var Freq_Du = $('#dura_values').val();
                        var Freq_Mil= $('#text_mil').val();

                        debugger;

                        var obj = {};
                        obj.ServiceID = ServiceID;
                        obj.frequency = frequency;
                        obj.Freq_Du = Freq_Du;
                        obj.Freq_Mi= Freq_Mil;
                        updatedata(obj);

                    });
                });
             }
         alert("12-1");
                function updatedata(obj) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Maintenance.aspx/updateselect_data",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{'ServiceID':'" + obj.ServiceID + "','frequency':'" + obj.frequency + "','Freq_Du':'" + obj.Freq_Du + "','Freq_Mil':'" + obj.Freq_Mil + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                    success:function(result)
                    {
                        alert("15-1");
                        debugger;
             var up = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
     $("#txt_repeat" + obj.frequency).html(obj.frequency);
            $("#dura_values" + obj.Freq_Duration).html(obj.Freq_Duration);
            $("#text_mil" + obj.Freq_Mileage).html(obj.Freq_Mileage);

            $("#text_mil" + obj.frequency + obj.Freq_Duration + obj.Freq_Mileage).html(obj.frequency + obj.Freq_Duration + obj.Freq_Mileage);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        var r = error.responseText;
                        var errorMessage = r.Message;
                         alert(errorMessage);
                        alert(r);
                        alert("error")
                    }

                });
                }
```

data in database table like this

```
 Service ID frequency Freq_Du Freq_Mil
    1           2         month          1200
```

and i display data in page  like this

```
 Service ID    Info
    1           2 month 1200
```

now when i update this record changes reflect in database table but not reflect in table which i  display in page

i concatenate data in 1 cell  like this

```
 var example = $("#services_schdulue").DataTable({
                        "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                        "columns":[
                            {
                                "title": "Service ID",
                                "data": "Service ID"
                            },{
                                "title": "frequency",
                                "data": "frequency",
                                "visible": false
                            }, {
                                "title": "Freq_Du",
                                "data": "Freq_Du",
                                "visible": false
                            },{
                                "title": "Freq_Mil",
                                "data": "Freq_Mil",
                                "render": function(data, type, row){
                 return row.frequency + row.Freq_Du+ row.Freq_Mil
                                }
                            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters don't match.
In your webmethod the method signature requires

```
 int ServiceID, string frequency, string Freq_Du, and string Freq_Mil
```

In your ajax post it's

```
data: "{'SID':'" + obj.ServiceID + "','frequency':'" + obj.frequency + "','Freq_Du':'" + obj.Freq_Du + "','Freq_Mil':'" + obj.Freq_Mil + "'}".
```

The `data: "{...}"` will simply pass a string to your `updateselect_data(int, string, string, string)`. Don't expect too much of your computer. It doesn't know how to convert a string to an int without explicitly instruction.

Comment: You either change your updateselect_data(int, string, string, string) to updateselect_data(string) and parse the json string at webmethod which makes no sense to me or post your ajax like data: {ServiceID: obj.ServiceID, frequency: obj.frequency.....}.

Comment: so how i covert SID into int in jquery ?

Comment: CHECK UPDATE QUESTION PLEASE @Nathan